# Название графического представления аудиосигнала

Tags: значение-слов

Согласно Википедии, эту штуку называют "сигналограмма". Но если попытаться найти такое слово в словарях, то оно обнаруживает другое значение: носитель информации, то есть магнитная лента, пластинка, диск и т.д. А как же тогда называть эту штуку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение**. Строго говоря, такие изображения называют "волновые формы". Но это не представляется точным термином. Как минимум есть другой точный технический термин, спектрограмма, который используют для описания другой формы представления аудиосигнала. Есть слово кардиограмма. И оно тоже означает именно графическое представление информации. Полагаю, тут тоже должен быть конкретный термин, некая *-грамма. Возможно, вопрос стоит поставить даже иначе: корректно ли называть такую графическую информацию сигналограммой?

Comment: Если в Хроме нажать правой кнопкой мыши на ваше изображение и выбрать "Найти картинку (Google)", то увидим ссылку на Википедию, где говорится: "Динамический диапазон — это разница (или соотношение) между самым громким и самым тихим звуком, выраженная в децибелах". Ссылка по теме: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hRE2RKUV2E

Comment: А причём тут динамический диапазон? Вопрос о графическом выражении этой информации, а не децибельном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевод слова *waveform* как "волновая форма" (как и замена в ряде слов корня "звук" на неудобное для произношения "аудио") мне представляется неудачным, "кустарным". В докомпьютерную эпоху такое изображение уверенно называли **осциллограммой** (как специалисты, так и радиолюбители). Возможно, попытки использовать другое наименование для компьютерного варианта *временны́х* графиков связаны с представлением, что слово "осциллограмма" связано исключительно со словом "осциллограф", поскольку на практике она обычно наблюдалась на экране этого прибора (буквально, показывавшем *графики колебаний - "осцилляций"*). Однако и в технической литературе на графики часто ссылались как на "осциллограммы". Термины "*сонограмма*" (для звука) или "*эпюра*" (в общем случае) всегда воспринимались как проявление излишнего педантизма и не были распростанены даже в специальной литературе. В быту я бы по-прежнему ссылался на такие графики как на "*осциллограммы*" *звуковых дорожек* (здесь: левого и правого каналов).

Comment: Блестяще: ёмко, информативно и по делу. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Александр, а что закрывает последняя кавычка? Ещё мне кажется, что после "буквально" не нужна запятая.

Comment: Кавычка осталась после редактирования, по недосмотру (убрал). Запятая мне представляется нужной, поскольку слово относится _не к глаголу_ ("буквально показывает"), а к одному из слов, выделенных кавычками в начинающемся с этого глагола выражении. Смысловую связь со смежным глаголом потребовалось разорвать, сделав слово вводным.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, сложный случай...